# .NET MAUI - Nested Tab within a Tab

Tags: c#, xaml, tabs, maui

I am working on an app to display some sports statistics, namely Standings in this example. I have it working where I have "Overall", "Conference", and "Division" tabs when I select the "Standings" page, no problems there. I am having trouble nesting tabs within tabs though. For instance, when I go to the "Conference" page, I want "Eastern" and "Western" as subtabs. I tried adding another tab control, but I am not seeing any difference.

```
<FlyoutItem Route="standings" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <Tab Title="Standings" Route="standings" Icon="standings.png">
        <ShellContent Route="overallstandings"
                      Style="{StaticResource StandingsShell}"
                      Title="Overall"
                      Icon="overall.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:OverallStandingsPage}" />
        <ShellContent Route="conferencestandings"
                      Style="{StaticResource StandingsShell}"
                      Title="Conference"
                      Icon="conference.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:EasternConferenceStandingsPage}">
                      <Tab Title="Conference">
                          <ShellContent Route="easternconferencestandings"
                            Style="{StaticResource StandingsShell}"
                            Title="Eastern"
                            Icon="eastern.png"
                            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:EasternConferenceStandingsPage}" />
                          <ShellContent Route="westernconferencestandings"
                            Style="{StaticResource StandingsShell}"
                            Title="Western"
                            Icon="western.png"
                            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:WesternConferenceStandingsPage}" />
                      </Tab>
        </ShellContent>
        <ShellContent Route="divisionstandings"
                      Style="{StaticResource StandingsShell}"
                      Title="Division"
                      Icon="division.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DivisionStandingsPage}" />
    </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

Comment: I would be surprised if the shell supported nested tabs.  You could try using a TabView inside of a TabbedPage

Comment: But the  "Conference" page also has the page content, how do you show the page content and the two tabs? So you can try to use the TabView as Jason said or set the "Conference" page as a flyout item.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try the TabView, since setting the Conference page as a FlyoutItem did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, and after a reread, I think what you are looking for, is the use of a tab bar. Try the following:

```
    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent Route="overallstandings"
                      Style="{StaticResource StandingsShell}"
                      Title="Overall"
                      Icon="overall.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:OverallStandingsPage}" />
        <ShellContent Route="conferencestandings"
                      Style="{StaticResource StandingsShell}"
                      Title="Conference"
                      Icon="conference.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:EasternConferenceStandingsPage}">
            <Tab Title="Conference">
                <ShellContent Route="easternconferencestandings"
                            Style="{StaticResource StandingsShell}"
                            Title="Eastern"
                            Icon="eastern.png"
                            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:EasternConferenceStandingsPage}" />
                <ShellContent Route="westernconferencestandings"
                            Style="{StaticResource StandingsShell}"
                            Title="Western"
                            Icon="western.png"
                            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:WesternConferenceStandingsPage}" />
            </Tab>
        <ShellContent Route="divisionstandings"
                      Style="{StaticResource StandingsShell}"
                      Title="Division"
                      Icon="division.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DivisionStandingsPage}" />
    </TabBar>
```

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't seem to do the trick

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @DustinB, I just found another solution using TabBar that I think is what you are looking for. Please see my updated answer.